# How to conditionally delete elements from list-of-tuples?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, idioms

```
>>> x=[("x1","x2","x3"),("x1","x2"),("x2","x3"),("x3","x4")]
>>> x
[('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), ('x1', 'x2'), ('x2', 'x3'), ('x3', 'x4')]
```

I want to delete the tuple in the list--x ,if `len(x[id])==3` ,`len(x[0]==3)` ,so it will be deleted ,`[('x1', 'x2'), ('x2', 'x3'), ('x3', 'x4')]` is what i wanted,how can i write the code?

```
[del element if len(element[id]==3) for id,element in enumerate(x)]

invalid syntax.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to filter elements, *keeping* everything not length 3:

```
x = [el for el in x if len(el) != 3]
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), ('x1', 'x2'), ('x2', 'x3'), ('x3', 'x4')]
>>> [el for el in x if len(el) != 3]
[('x1', 'x2'), ('x2', 'x3'), ('x3', 'x4')]
```

Comment: Or as a slightly less pythonic way: `x = filter(lambda el: len(el) != 3, x)`.

Comment: which, in Python 3, produces an iterator and not a list.